# Visual Composer: Where do I find the source code of a custom element?

Tags: plugins, theme-development

I am trying to make some custom changes in a Wordpress template build on Visual Composer, but have not found the source codes of Visual Composers elements within my Wordpress installation.

I found a vc_map():

```
vc_map( array(
    "name"     => __( "Contact / info form", "vh" ),
    "base"     => "mid_contact_form",
    "icon"     => "icon-wpb-ui-gap-content",
    "class"    => "",
    "category" => __( "by AutoRepair", "vh" ),
    "params"   => array(
    array(
            "type"        => "textfield",
            "class"       => "",
            "heading"     => __( "Custom class", "vh" ),
            "admin_label" => true,
            "param_name"  => "custom_class",
            "value"       => "",
            "description" => __( "Custom class", "vh" )
        ),
    array(
            "type"        => "textfield",
            "class"       => "",
            "heading"     => __( "Contact form Id", "vh" ),
            "admin_label" => true,
            "param_name"  => "contact_id",
            "value"       => "",
            "description" => __( "Contact form Id", "vh" )
        )
)));
```

which seems to be responsible for the appearing of the Element

> "Contact / info form"

but do not know where to get the source code of this element from.

P.S. I am grepping the hell out of my whole wordpress installation and the source code seems to be nowhere?

Comment: I'd suggest going down the rabbit hole. Start by grepping for `function vc_map` within the Visual Composer plugin directory. This should show how it is handling the parameter array. Presumably this function, or perhaps another one further on down the bunny hole will handle the display based on the `type` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of not finding the elements was that the installed Wordpress version of my template ([Cohhe Autorepair](http://cohhe.com/demo/autorepair/)) installed a template specific plugin, which was only compressed in the local (offline) template version. Uncompressing the plugin yielded success with

```
grep "some text" -nr /templateFolder
```

The final directory was given by:

```
/wp-content/plugins/autorepair-plugin/lib/functions/shortcodes.php
```